# Let $S=\{0,2,4,6,8\}$, $T=\{1,3,5,7\}$. Determine whether each of the following sets of ordered pairs is a function with domain $S$ and co-domain $T$.

Tags: functions

> Let $S=\{0,2,4,6,8\}$ and $T=\{1,3,5,7\}$. Determine whether each of the following sets of ordered pairs is a function with
>   domain $S$ and co-domain $T$.

1. $\{(6,3),(2,1),(0,3),(8,7),(4,5)\}$
   **TRUE**
   This is a function
2. $\{(2,1),(4,5),(6,3)\}$
   **FALSE**
   Not all domain values used
3. $\{(0,2),(2,4),(4,6),(6,0),(8,2)\}$
   **FALSE**
   Domain values mapped to values outside of co-domain
4. $\{(2,3),(4,7),(0,1),(6,5),(8,7)\}$
   **TRUE**
   This is a function
5. $\{(6,1),(0,3),(4,1),(0,7),(2,5),(8,5)\}$
   **FALSE**
   $0$ is mapped twice

Currently, I am unsure about number 3, can the domain values be mapped to itself as shown or does that invalidate it as a function in this situation since the co-domain has specified values? Thanks!

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: You can use `$\{1,2,3\}$` to show $\{1,2,3\}$. Please try not to use ALL CAPITAL LETTERS. I can be understood as _shouting_. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The only places it is allowed to be mapped to is the codomain.  If the elements which are mapped to themselves happen to be elements of both the domain and codomain simultaneously, then there is no problem, but when those elements are only members of the domain and not the codomain, then you run into a problem describing it as a function from $S$ to $T$ as you would have hoped to do.  Note that a function, $f$, from $S$ to $T$ is a *relation* from $S$ to $T$ (*which satisfies some extra conditions*), implying that every $(s,t)\in f$ satisfies $s\in S$ and $t\in T$.

Comment: thanks! that clears my question up!

Answer (score 1):

The domain values of a function must be mapped to values in the codomain, so, as indicated in the comments, your work is correct.